# Dependency issue on installing gstreamer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, gstreamer

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and the DVD player stopped working. After some research I was trying to reinstall gstreamer but I ran into an issue that seems related to Ubuntu 18.04 and that is beyond my understanding. Here is the output of the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version (1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version (1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-tools set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version (1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-alsa is already the newest version (1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1).
gstreamer1.0-alsa set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.14.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help is really appreciated (in particular by the kids :) )

Answer (score 3):

I had some struggle with it too, but I found a .deb package which solved the problem:

From https://launchpad.net/~ci-train-ppa-service/+archive/ubuntu/3267-deletedppa/+build/14926540  download the

[gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~ci-train-ppa-service/+archive/ubuntu/3267-deletedppa/+build/14926540/+files/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb)

and install it.